# c++ repetitive fwrite fflush take long time

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

In a program for my Raspberry Pi 3B, I am writing a binary file in non sequential mode.
So i have to write a block in a specific position in file.

In my loop I call in order: memcpy to copy the block that I need in my buffer that will write on file, fseek to point the position where this block should be wirte, fwrite to write the block and fflush.

After some loops the functions fwrite or fflush stuck and take long time to complete even if the block size is almost the same for all calls.

My function that I call multiple times:

```
static void writeChunk(FILE* total, unsigned char *data, T_Chunk* chk, int HEIGHT, int totalStride, int seekStride){

    char* buffer = new char[chk->stride];
    for(int row = 0; row < HEIGHT; ++row){
        auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

        memcpy( buffer, data + (row*chk->stride), chk->stride);


        //total.seekp((row * totalStride) + seekStride, total.beg);

        start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        fseek(total, (row * totalStride) + seekStride, SEEK_SET);

        auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        if(chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() > 150)
            cout << "Elapsed time in microseconds fseek : " 
            << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count()
            << endl;
        //total.write(buffer, chk->stride);


        start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        fwrite(buffer, 1, chk->stride, total);



        end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        if(chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() > 150)
            cout << "Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( " << chk->stride << " ): " 
            << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count()
            << endl;


        start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        fflush(total);



        end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        if(chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() > 150)
            cout << "Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( " << chk->stride << " ): " 
            << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count()
            << endl;



        //total.flush();

    }
    free(buffer);
    free(data);

}
```

And there is some ouput:

```
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7552 ): 166
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7296 ): 207
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7488 ): 156
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7680 ): 162
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7616 ): 164
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7488 ): 158
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7680 ): 160
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7616 ): 151
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7296 ): 195
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7296 ): 175
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7296 ): 179
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7552 ): 23034
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7552 ): 27514
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7680 ): 34438
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7680 ): 27492
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7680 ): 26612
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7616 ): 27856
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7616 ): 27502
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7616 ): 27366
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7616 ): 27444
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7616 ): 27881
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7616 ): 27593
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7616 ): 27417
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7552 ): 27582
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7552 ): 27374
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7552 ): 27517
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7552 ): 24657
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7488 ): 199
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7488 ): 27734
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7488 ): 24747
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7488 ): 24714
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7488 ): 187
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7360 ): 228
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7360 ): 27808
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7360 ): 24886
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7360 ): 24601
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7680 ): 203
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7680 ): 196
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7680 ): 28047
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7680 ): 24879
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7680 ): 24948
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7360 ): 202
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7360 ): 26000
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7616 ): 24685
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7616 ): 38157
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7616 ): 38434
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7616 ): 38301
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7616 ): 38315
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7488 ): 29295
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7488 ): 38358
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7488 ): 38366
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7488 ): 36493
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7488 ): 36495
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7488 ): **5432436**
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7488 ): 982
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7488 ): **175095**
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7552 ): 154
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7616 ): 224
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7424 ): 279
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7488 ): 25078
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7488 ): 27502
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7488 ): 27483
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7360 ): 28146
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7360 ): 27558
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7360 ): 27403
Elapsed time in microseconds fwrite ( 7616 ): 27819
Elapsed time in microseconds fflush ( 7616 ): 27480
```

Why the time is not almost the same for all calls?

Why after some calls it stucks for so long time like 5432436 or 175095 microseconds as you can see from logs?

This problem affect another thread that try to read from a different file, so I guess id a problem with I/O buffer.

Is the problem on my code or on the HW that I use?

How can I improve my code? I don't really need speed but it should not lock the other I/O proccess.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing that the caches are used for the fast writes. Do you really need `fflush()`? Is there another process reading the file at the same time?

Comment: Fflush writes to disk, but disk also has cache. Once it's full, you get disk speed

Comment: I use fflush to not use all I/O buffer that I thought was the problem.
There is another process that read but a different file.
So the problem could be the disk cache. The disk is a SD card, a Samsung EVO Plus with write speed at 20Mb/s, the file is around 260Mb so it would take less or more 15seconds, but it will take longer than this.
Is there any way to manage the disk buffer or prevent to full it?